# Why inflater.inflate not responding?

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater

This is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_movie_trailers, parent, false);

    final Trailer trailer = this.getTrailer(position);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.adapter_movie_trailer_thumb);
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imageView, trailer.thumb,
            R.drawable.without_poster);

    TextView trailerTitle = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.adapter_movie_trailer_title);
    trailerTitle.setText(trailer.title);

    TextView trailerDuration = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.adapter_movie_trailer_duration);
    trailerDuration.setText(trailer.duration);

    notifyDataSetChanged();

    return rowView;
}
```

My app seems to be in an endless-loop while trying to inflate the rowView. Why?

Comment: why do you need `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `getView`. Remove it.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Set a breakpoint and check if it's really the line inflater.inflate() where it stucks.

Comment: You do realize that by calling notifyDataSetChange() the listview will call getView again? I guess you should remove that from getView method.

Comment: I solved. About de notifyDataSetChanged was a test, I set it in my OnClickListener as I need to reload data whenever the user click in my row. Thx